# Is it possible to add a tooltip when hovering over a drawing (annotation) using stock charts of Anychart

Tags: annotations, tooltip, drawing, stock, anychart

I would like to know if there is anyway to add a tool-tip while hovering over an annotation or a drawing using stock charts i anychart.
for example, if i draw a rectangle, i would like to show a tool-tip to with the values of the rectangle(start and end dates, and upper and lower price).
if there aren't any built-in functions to do so, are there any event listeners for hovering over an annotation? then maybe when the event of hovering the mouse-in i could create an html element and then hide it on the even of mouse-out.
**another solution might be by creating labels on the xAxis and on the yAxis. but i could not find anything to add labels in a specific location.
any suggestion is appreciated.**

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the current version of the library 8.7.0 doesn't support tooltip or events to implement custom interactivity with Stock chart annotations. 
If you want to add labels on the axes, you can use [text axis markers](https://docs.anychart.com/Axes_and_Grids/Text_Markers). The article is about basic charts, but it will work for Stock charts. The difference is that you should call API not from a chart, but from Stock chart plot.
For example `chart.textMarker()` should be replaced with `chart.plot(0).textMarker()`, and that's it.